# Galaxy S3 turning on and off repeatedly even after factory reset

Tags: boot-loop

I have a bricked samsung galaxy s3! It is shutting off and on again and I need to remove the battery to make it stop. I have tried the following...

-tapping out stuck power button

-options in recovery menu (reboot, wipe cache, wipe data and factory rest)

-I have wiped and installed fresh from Odin, which was difficult because my charge port is apparently not working great.

Once I reset with Odin my phone booted up nicely and walked me through setting up my phone. Once i got to the main screen my hopes and dreams were promptly crushed and the phone started shutting  down and restarting again..

Thoughts?

Answer (score -2):

Reload your BOOTLOADER because that is what will be stopping your device from booting sincerely it works a bit like BIOS. I, sadly, dont have any tips on how to do so though. Google search maybe?